# LoaderManager on Activity with multiple Fragments (on ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I have an `Activity` which hosts 4 `Fragments` on a `ViewPager`. Each of these `Fragments` calls `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this)`.

The documentation says the first parameter is an **ID**. So I find myself wondering, the fact that I use `0` as the id for **every fragment** inside the same `ViewPager` does it affect performance?